# Integration of signal in embedded matlab function with variable timestep size

Tags: matlab, signals, simulink, robotics

I need to get a position from a velocity signal. I need to do it in SIMULINK and MATLAB and I need to do it to control a real robot. 
I can't use the standard continuous time integrator of SIMULINK because my time step changes at each iteration.

Therefore I was thinking to use a simple forward-euler method in the following embedded matlab function.

I am not sure this is the best solution and therefore I would like to know your opinion about it|

```
function pCurr = fcn(vCurr, dt,p0)
%#codegen

persistent pOld
persistent vOld
if isempty(pOld)
    pOld = p0;
end

if isempty(vOld)
    vOld = vCurr;
end


pOld = pOld + trapz([vOld vCurr])*dt;
vOld = vCurr;
pCurr = pOld;
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're controlling a real robot, presumably with a real-time processor, how are using a variable time step?  That's very unusual.

Comment: Hi @PhilGoddard this is the first time for me too. I don't know why this is happening. We changed architecture and this is what I have now. For me too it is really strange but I need to deal with it I think. It does not change too much but it does change and we can see how long every cycle takes and this is why I was thinking of using this number in the integration loop.